# script to run through files in directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to write a script, which automates the following procedure:
Every week I copy about 5-10 video files to a directory and delete the audio stream of each file, using avcodec. 
I thought this was a good starting point to write my first script in bash.
It should check the filenames in the directory (00001.MTS,00002.MTS,...) and execute the command for each file.
I come from python and matlab, where I would be able to write this script using a for or a while loop.

I would be glad to not get the finished code for my problem, but a few links where I can find the necessary information.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have you started? What have you tried so far? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-while-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Check `man find`. It's a flexible and powerful tool that you should definitely think about whenever you hear "several files from a directory".  Whether you want to just *find* them (-print), or in this case *run a command* on every one of them (-exec):

```
find "$HOME"/some/videos -type f -name "*.MTS" \
    -exec av_encoder_too --remove-audio ... {} \;
```

Note:

- the literal semicolon at the end **needs** to be escaped with a backslash.
- the `{}` is a **literal** pair of braces -- that is where find will substitute in each file it finds when runs the commands.
- the first backslash at the end of the line is just to split a long command into two lines.  You could just as easily omit it and write it all as one long command line

Of course you'll need to supply correct values for

- the directory `"$HOME"/some/videos`
- the encoder tool and it's args `av_encoder_too --remove-audio ...`

After you have this working, as a next step on your path to learning, I recommend exploring the `xargs` command -- It's a different approach to issues of "do something to many files".

Happy hacking,
./ddd

Comment: thanks ./ddd! 
I'll try this next week, as I am only working one day a week on the linux computer.

Comment: I would like to use the following command, to cut the audio stream of the video:
"avconv -i [input_file] -vcodec copy -an [output_file]"
What can I supply for [input file] and [output file], if I want to have it done for all the files in the directory?

Comment: find is pretty smart about replacing `{}`, so you can have it several times in the command (in between `-exec` and `\;`).  So something like `find "$HOME"/some/videos -type f -name "*.MTS" -exec avconv -i {} -vcodec copy -an {}.new_extension \;`